# TestNG is not visible inside preferences after installing (In Eclipse LUNA)

Tags: java, testng, eclipse-luna

I have downloaded TestNG from Help->Install New Software->TestNG - http://beust.com/eclipse , after installing I should be able to see inside window->preferrences or while doing run as I should be able to see TestNG option . ( I am using eclipse LUNA)

I have installed it properly but due to some problem I am not able to see the TestNG option.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue ? Or is there any setting is there to make the TestNG option should be available while doing run as ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the eclipse . Then it is working fine.Actually I was using Luna (may be the problem was in Version) then I have used Eclipse Keplar.

Answer (score 0):

Any Eclipse TestNG will work Please check your java version if it is less that 1.7 version then TestNG will not show. but still you in see TestNG installed software Tab.

There is some issue with 1.6 and TestGN compatibility

Answer (score 0):

TestNG supporting JDK 1.5 and 1.6 is 6.8.21. 
If your are installing TestNG from the Market Place / Installed new software from Eclipse latest version of TestNG i.e. 6.9.xxx gets installed which is not compatible with jre6.

Solution is to upgrade the jre to the latest version available.